# Vulnerable Javascript Library; is it a non-issue if the JS is loaded only for the browser side?

Tags: javascript, security

Client has made a security audit and it came back with VULNERABLE JAVASCRIPT LIBRARY (for jQuery and Underscore)

And that I don't understand; the JS library is given with the site, but doesn't have a link to the server; The server is apache, not a node or one of the JS based servers.

Basically, if you were to break jQuery in half, and run some weird code, it cannot reach the server in a different way as if you were to run that code from the chrome console. And at that point, nothing would be safe.

So if a JS library is loaded only for display and features on the rendered website and not for any server work; is it then a non-issue?

I kinda need an ELI5 for this issue.

Comment: We would need to see what specific vulnerability this audit has reported, and what your accepted risk matrix is, in order to answer whether this is a concern/issue or if it's even truly a vulnerability. So, this needs details/clarity and is probably ultimately opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case: No, it is not safe.

A vulnerability in a JS library on a website could lead to, for example, an XSS vulnerability allowing an attacker to issue same-origin Ajax requests from a genuine user’s browser after sending them a malicious link.

The actual threats would depend on the specific vulnerabilities.

Comment: The thing I'm not understanding is that if it could use the JS that is loaded for the browser; then anybody could do so via the console, without even needing to break jQuery to do so? Like I don't understand how someone that has the site loaded could then use that library and break the site.

Comment: @Fredy31 — Please reread the middle paragraph of this answer. The attacker is a third party.

Comment: Maybe I'm seeing it wrong; I see a library only given to the browser for display just like if you were to take a sealed bottle of Gatorade at the convenience store. Its been given to you; sealed. If you were to put some cyanide in your bottle; its not like it will put cyanide into all bottles. It wont change anything. You broke it for yourself, congratulations, but nothing changes for gatorade corp at large.

Comment: Sorry we commented at the same time; But still, how the hell would someone be able to change the JS that is applied on the page via an URL? Also, on this website, there is absolutely no private information that is transferred. The worst case is a contact form. There is no private section, no items that can be bought. Its just a display case for a company. Breaking the site would like be breaking the front facing window of a store, the kind that is separated from the store itself. Cool you broke it, but I change the window pane and we are back to square one.

Comment: I suggest you read the Wikipedia article about XSS attacks.

Comment: I read it but I'm no expert in server stuff and cybersecurity. Like I said, I need an ELI5. Like I see, okay, you can inject code into the page that would fuck with the user and its session. But the big thing that I dont see is how the hell does someone inject the code in the first place? Like if the files coming from my server are clean, I struggle to see how someone from the outside could inject code to the other users. It would need something like the users have a compromised plugin on their browser or a compromised device? But at that point, they have bigger problems than an XSS attack?

Comment: ...and if the code my site serves in general contains the attack, then I have bigger problems than an XSS attack on my users and it makes no sense that i would protect myself for an exploit that happens after the files I serve have been compromised.

Comment: “But the big thing that I dont see is how the hell does someone inject the code in the first place” — I mentioned a malicious link in my original answer. The wikipedia article has numerous examples showing how code is injected through the URL.